# C - discard pointer parameter

Tags: c, pointers, parameters

I'm not sure how to phrase this question so I'll give an example of what I'm looking to do.

I have a function that gets the next byte from a FIFO.

```
void fifoGet(uint8_t * byte) {
   *byte = somefunction();
}
```

I'm making a function to flush the FIFO

```
void fifoFlush(void) {
    uint8_t i;
    uint8_t discardByte;

    for (i=0; i<fifoLength; i++) {
        fifoGet(&discardByte);
    }

}
```

What I'm wondering, since I don't need that `discardByte`, can I get around allocating that memory and just pass a void pointer to fifoGet()?

Something like

```
void fifoFlush(void) {
    uint8_t i;

    for (i=0; i<fifoLength; i++) {
        fifoGet(&void);
    }

}
```

Comment: no you can't. you will halt the program in some case. this is destructive. the original way is good enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the void approach would cause the behaviour of the program to be undefined as you'll be dereferencing a pointer to unknown memory.

Your using `discardByte` is probably the best thing to do.

Comment: `discardByte` has function scope so it is released when the function `fifoFlush` ends  - so the storage issue is moot.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin it's not so much a storage issue, I was just hoping to get around the (admittedly minute) overhead of creating/disposing of the variable.

Comment: Not without refactoring fifoGet

Comment: @user3817250 you overconsidered the problem. allocating variable in stack is done in one shot. allocating one more won't bring any overhead, literally.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that. However, it is always better to err on the side of defined behavior and spend a momentary `byte` than end up outsmarting yourself.

Answer (score 2):

it won't take too much to change your structure to:

```
uint8_t fifoGet() {
   return somefunction();
}

void fifoFlush(void) {
    uint8_t i;

    for (i=0; i<fifoLength; i++) {
        fifoGet();
    }

}
```

Comment: I agree, this would be how to handle my specific example, however in my actual application fifoGet() is in ROM and can't be modified. I should have included that in the question.

Comment: From that standpoint why not have `fifoGet` return either `a value` or `NULL` allowing `fifoflush () { while (fifoGet() != NULL) ; }` (that was in response to HuStmpHrrr), your ROM changes things. You could make the last element a `sentinel element` set to `NULL` and keep a pointer to `fifo` which to empty could point to the last element `NULL`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin i can't agree with that. what prevents `fifoGet` from returning valid `0`? it's not cool for a function mangling different type of values into one return type.

Comment: I see your point. I was thinking pointers and you have it as uint8_t. 0/NULL would be indistinguishable.